# My money transfer went to the wrong bank, what can I do to reverse it?

Tags: banking, money-transfer, online-payment, mistakes

I have 2 different bank accounts with a bank and a credit union. A payment through seller was posted into the wrong account. What can I do to reverse the transaction?

Answer (score 9):

I gather from your question that you have 2 bank accounts, and your agent (seller who sells assets you owned) posted the proceeds to the wrong bank account, but it’s still your bank account that the money went to.

(*Frame challenge*)

Instead or reversing the transaction and taking the risk that the seller doesn’t get it right this time, or that they just keep the money you’ve returned to them, you can make a payment from one of your accounts to the other. To do this, you could write a cheque, use internet banking, draw cash, etc.

Comment: Strongly recommend against drawing cash and carrying it from bank to credit union or vice versa. Checks/cheques or internet banking is by far the preferable method.